# Can I make a ledger board that is two 2x6 and one 2x12 thick?

Tags: deck, ledger

I have an odd setup right now with my front deck; it uses steel triangles bolted to the foundation to hold the beams for my deck. A couple of them have let go and need replacing.

[image]

That steel is one of the brackets, but I’m planning to replace these with ledger board bolted to the concrete.

The only challenge I’m having is the best way to get the original floor height. Currently it’s two 2x6s tall, above the top of the steel bracket. If I put a ledger board there and set the joists on top of the ledger board, I’ll still be 5.5” too low.

Could I make a ledger board that is one 2x6 and one 2x12 (to get the height back to original)?

Here's perhaps a better mock-up of the design. The black horizontal line is the grade. The round column represents the helical pile. The 2x6 get the 2x12 out past the brick, and with the bottoms of the 2x6 and 2x12 flush I get 6" of rise that I can set the joists on.

[image]

Comment: Those steel angle supports offer better support than only a ledge board would offer. How is the deck structure being supported in your new design?

Comment: The problem is that those supports stick out 5’, forming a right triangle. At the tip of those triangles are the columns that support the roof overhand. Two of the brackets have already had their bolts snap off (plus using them isn’t too code anymore). My new design is ledger board on the house and helical piles support the beam under the columns.

Comment: Oh another thing to mention is there’s only one bolt holding those brackets to the concrete and nothing fastens the beam to the steel.

Comment: Would it make things easier if you used joist hangars to attach the joists to you ledger board?

Comment: I'm not surprised the angle brackets have failed.  The 5' out from the house distance you mentioned is a very big cantilever.  That puts a very high tension (pull out) force on the top fasteners of those angle brackets.  I bet (without trying to calculate it), it's several thousand, of not tens of thousands of pounds.

Comment: Could you mark up your picture of the house to indicate where it is that you need the additional height? I'm having trouble visualizing where your drawing fits in with what we see in the picture.

Comment: @SteveSh, it sounds like the other end of the 5' bracket was attached to the post supporting the other edge of the deck. Five feet would be a pretty long cantilever, but it doesn't sound like these were actually cantilevered.

Comment: @FreeMan - You may be right.  But I can't tell that from the photo or OP's description.

Comment: Ultimately I’d remove the steel. A 2x6 ledger would be fastened to the concrete with its top of the same height as the top of the steel. Helical piles would support the beams, instead of being on the cantilever steel brackets. And then I was wondering if I could fasten a 2x12 against the 2x6 ledger to get my joists high enough for the desired floor height.

Comment: Why not simply attach the 2x12" ledger directly and skip the 2x6? That's the part that I'm missing...

Comment: Because whatever I use for a ledger will have the same height as the top of the steel brackets. Currently a beam sits on the top of the brackets, and then joists on top of the beam. So the floor is 11” above the top of the brackets. The 2x12 is required for two reasons. One is because the brick fascade stick out 1” past the concrete, and two I need the extra height above the top of the ledger to sets joists on top of to get the right floor height. Perhaps I can do a better diagram.

Comment: @FreeMan does the new diagram help explain what I'm trying to say a little better?

Comment: That looks to me like it's going to change from using the bolts in shear to using them as levers. It seems like a significant structural change and I would want a structural engineer to sign off on it if I was doing that.

Comment: @KMJ perhaps, but I doubt it'd be much more different than two 2x6's...

Comment: If you're confident in that, do it. Personally I'd take it to my structural engineer.

Comment: Looks like a great place for water to sit, never dry, and rot it out. If you go that route, I'd recommend a good deal of water intrusion prevention (flashing for starters).

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean yup I’d use flashing regardless, but this is also a covered deck as the roof of the house goes over all of it, so it doesn’t see much water.

Comment: @KMJ, the bolts near always act as levers due to the weak bearing strength of the wood. Mode Im and Is from the figure on page 6 of https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-TR12-1510.pdf rarely determine a connection's strength. Try your favorite connection geometry and local species at https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-TR12-1510.pdf, and note how high the Im and Is capacities are in comparison to other modes of failure (lower strengths for other modes implies that the connection fails under these modes before the stress can cause a mode Im or Is failure).

Answer (score 2):

See [IRC R507.9.1.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR507.9.1.3). There's a table for 1" of sheathing instead of your 2x6 spacer. If the 1" spacer is sufficient instead of your 1.5" spacer, then the table has a bolting schedule that you can use.

I suggest 2-1/2" wide chunks of wood at each bolt location so that any water that falls back there can escape or at least dry out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ledger. Put in 2 helical piles near the house and put a beam across the top of them. Set joists on the beams. The joists can extend past the beam a bit. No water retention problem, not ledger twisting problem (which is a problem with your stacked proposal.) The deck will now be structurally independent from the house.

Comment: The house typically provides the deck's lateral system. Without the ledger, it will need braces to prevent it from toppling. It looks like there's a potential alternative ledger spot against the house, but without a plan view of the deck's footprint, it's presumptuous to assume that the alternative ledger doesn't run along a very narrow width of deck (making it insufficient).